# Как узнать лайкнув ли эту запись пользователь с определенным id

Tags: php, вконтакте, vkontakte-api

Всем привет. Такая проблема. Есть ссылка на запись вконтакте [https://vk.com/idххххххх?w=wall239752675_486](https://vk.com/id%D1%85%D1%85%D1%85%D1%85%D1%85%D1%85%D1%85?w=wall239752675_486)
Как узнать лайкнув ли эту запись пользователь например с `id1`

Пробовал использовать метод [`likes.getList`](https://vk.com/dev/likes.getList) но ничего так и не получается, вернее когда сформированную ссылку вставляю в адресную строку в браузере все работает, а когда поробую в php нет.

Вот кусок кода который я использую в php

```
$rr = json_decode(file_get_contents("ссылка"));

print_r ($rr);
```

Прошу знающих людей помочь.

Answer (score 1):

```
https://api.vk.com/method/likes.getList?type=post&owner_id=1&item_id=472308
```

Ответ в `json`, количество лайков в параметре `count`:

```
$resp = json_decode($response, true);
echo 'Количество лайков: '.$resp['response']['count'];
```

Comment: Я так понимаю Весь код будет иметь такой выд

$response = file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/likes.getList?type=post&owner_id=1&item_id=472308');
$resp = json_decode($response, true);
echo 'Количество лайков: '.$resp['response']['count'];

Comment: @Анатолий попробуйте.

Comment: Вообщем такой код 

$response = file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/likes.getList?type=post&owner_id=1&item_id=472308");
$resp = json_decode($response, true);
echo 'Количество лайков: '.$resp['response']['count'].'';

Выдает мне такую ошибку Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.vk.com/method/likes.getList?type=post&owner_id=1&item_id=472308) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream:

В чем может бить проблема?

Учусь на денвере

Comment: @Анатолий дело в том, что функции надо указать протокол, то бишь `https://`. Вписывайте полный путь: `https://api.vk.com/method/likes.getList?type=post&owner_id=1&item_id=472308`

Comment: Все работает, просто изменив https на http
Спасибо Вам большое

Comment: Может кому пригодится, вот весь мой код 

$response = file_get_contents("хттп://api.vk.com/method/likes.getList?type=post&owner_id=1&item_id=472308");

$resp = json_decode($response, true);

echo 'Количество лайков: '.$resp['response']['count'].'';

PS: Когда добавляю здесь комментарий удаляется в ссылках хттп!